# How to wrap characters with jQuery by count?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table, one of cells in each row contains cell with 13 characters.

```
<td class="need-to-wrap">0123456789012</td>
```

I need to wrap characters #10, 11 and 12 with span like this

```
<td class="need-to-wrap">012345678<span>901</span>2</td>
```

How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Sorry, misspelled in editing, now the code is visible

Comment: Please show your attempts first, and we can help you from there.   The community won't just provide a solution for you.

Comment: Sorry, I have no attempts. I'm newbie in jQuery.

Comment: `slice()` is your friend. You can accomplish this with plain javascript, no jQuery needed. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /(\d{9})(\d{3})(\d{1})/;
$('td.need-to-wrap').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text(); 
    text = text.replace(re, "$1<span>$2</span>$3");
    $this.html(text);
});
```